# Table per subclass mapping with Spring Data

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on implement a table per subclass mapping strategy using Spring Data Jpa and annotations, my doubt is regarding the autoincrement feature.

I have two classes, "Persona" and "Jugador", "Jugador" extends from "Persona".

I don't know if the autoincrement of the Id should be annotated on the parent class, the child class or in both.

Code sample:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="personas")
@Inheritance(strategy=JOINED)
public class Persona implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

@Entity
@Table(name="jugadores")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")

public class Jugador extends Persona {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

My doubt is when I think for instance if I do persist a "Jugador" and auto increment the ID what does ensure that the same ID in the parent table will be identical? and if I do the autoincrement only on the parent class how will the child class detect that in order to assign to itself the same id as the parent class so those can be joined?

I'm confused about how this will behave in the background, please help.

Answer (score 0):

An entity hierarchy should only ever define its identifier once so you should not be doing that in both the root entity class and the subclass as you have in your case.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Persona {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
}

@Entity
public class Jugador extends Persona {
}
```

If you look at your database tables, you'll notice that both the entity table for `Persona` and `Jugador` contain a column for the identifier.

If you find you need similar columns defined across varying entities but need differing identifier logic, the best way to map that is to instead use a `@MappedSuperclass`.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity<T> {
  // define common attribues here

  // define the identifier methods abstract
  // do not place any annotations on these methods here
  public abstract T getId();
  public abstract void setId(T id);
}

@Entity
public class EntityA extends AbstractBaseEntity<Integer> {
  // define EntityA attributes here

  // implement identifier getter/setter with annotations
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  public Integer getId() { return this.id; }
  public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
}

@Entity
public class EntityB extends AbstractBaseEntity<Long> {
  // define EntityB attributes here

  // implement identifier getter/setter with annotations
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  public Long getId() { return this.id; }
  public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

You can also apply `@Inheritance` here but you would do that on both `EntityA` and `EntityB` as needed as those are the root-entity for two differing entity hierarchies that just happen to share a common abstract interface thanks to `AbstractBaseEntity`.